# Connecting to Tor through Verizon

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, configuration

If my computer has a wireless connection to a Verizon wireless base connected via cable, do I need to do anything special before I can rely on Tor anonymity or can I just download Tor, install and browse with privacy?

Comment: This question is a bit vague (or maybe it's just me); can you try to clarify what you want? What's special or different about Verizon that makes you concerned that it wouldn't work like every other ISP?

Comment: I've downloaded the tor bundle and it won't connect (using Verizon Fios). Googling reveals that this is a known problem with Verizon's mindset, but I haven't found a workaround. Here's the log entry: "3/15/14, 23:43:04.726 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections."

Answer (score 1):

The connection via Verizon is not different from any other Internet connection. Just follow the [installation instruction](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and make sure to verify the signature (this [video](https://media.torproject.org/video/torbrowser-docs/How-to-verify-signatures-in-Windows.mp4) shows some details). After you have extracted all files you can click on `Start Tor Browser` and browse the Web.